# Every other ajax request on chrome takes 10 times as long

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I'm sending lots of http requests using javascript, and in chrome the first request will take around 30ms and the second will take around 300ms. Subsequent requests will alternate between the two irregardless of what kind of request I'm making. This doesn't happen in Firefox. And I should note that I'm running a dev server on my computer. Can anyone shed some light on this situation?

Here are pictures of chrome's timing tab:

[image: Connection 1]

[image: Connection 2]

As you can see, there's a very large gap in connection 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just encountered the same problem (but in webkit-based electron environment). And the solution is just to replace the domain "localhost" with the exactly IP "127.0.0.1". 
I'm afraid it is a bug in chrome.
Hopes it useful to you.

Comment: I don't work on that codebase anymore, but thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: This still seems to be happening in 2021. I made a demo video to show the difference in speeds between localhost and 127.0.0.1 as well as comparing to Firefox localhost: [Chrome localhost slow ajax calls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVCOR0xRmd0).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be waiting for server response.

Have you tried to debug the response. For instance adding server timing values to the response so you can see how long time it spends on the server?

Comment: I know the server is working fine because I don't have this issue in firefox. Why would the server only slow down for chrome? And from the picture I posted above (connection 2), there's a massive gap between the DNS lookup and the initial connection.